# Recommend a Maths Textbook for Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, book-recommendation

I am not a beginner to calculus. Till know I have learned about:
1. Functions - Domain,range,odd/even,periodic,compositemapping, etc.
2. Graphical transformations.
3. Evalution of limits, checking continuity differentiability and their theorems.
4. Derivative of functions, their theorems and application like monotonicity etc.
5. Definite and Indefinite Integration.
6. Differential Equations.

I need a textbook for much more advanced calculus according to my level, as I look forward to maths as career choice. Right now I need a book that have little bit of what I have already learned, so that I can practise it + more advanced and challenging calculus for deeper understanding.

Comment: Spivak's "Calculus" will show you how to think about calculus carefully and deeply.

Comment: I've looked for a few books and I have found these 4 to be the most widely used: 1.Spivak 2.Thomas&Finney 3.Apostol 4.Stewart. Which one of them would you recommend the Most?